# Консольная игра на c#

Tags: c#, .net

Я пиши небольшую консольую игру на c#. У меня есть структура инвентарь

```
namespace FightGame.Structs
{
    public struct Inventory
    {
        private int _totalProtection = 0;
        private int _totalProtectionQuality = 0;
        private List<Item> _items;

        public int TotalProtection => _totalProtection;
        public int TotalProtectionQuality => _totalProtectionQuality; 
        public List<Item> Items => _items;

        #region Costructors
        public Inventory()
        {
            _items = new();
        }
        public Inventory(List<Item> items)
        {
            _items = items;
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                _totalProtection += item.Protection;
                _totalProtectionQuality += item.ProtectionQuality;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        public static Inventory GenerateInventory(int countItem)
        {
            Inventory inventory = new();
            for (int i = 0; i < countItem; i++)
            {
                inventory.AddItemInInventory(Item.GenerateItem($"Item {i + 1}", 100, 100, 100, 3));
            }
            return inventory;
        }

        public void AddItemInInventory(Item item)
        {
            _items.Add(item);

            _totalProtection += item.Protection;
            _totalProtectionQuality += item.ProtectionQuality;
        }
        public void AddItemsInInvntory(List<Item> items)
        {
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                AddItemInInventory(item);
            }
        }
        public void PrintInventory()
        {
            if (_items.Count == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("Инвентарь пуст");
            else
                foreach (Item item in _items)
                    item.PrintItemInfo();
        }
        public static void PrintInventory(Inventory inventory)
        {
            if (inventory.Items.Count == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("Инвентарь пуст");
            else
                foreach (Item item in inventory.Items)
                    item.PrintItemInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

При добавлении в список предметов общая защита и общее качество защиты должны увеличиться. Самое интерестное что в списке появляется предмет, но общая защита и общее качество защиты не изменяются. Я отслеживаю это с помощью точек останова.
Вот скриншоты
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using FightGame.Scripts;
using FightGame.Structs;

namespace FightGame
{
    public static class Game
    {
        private static Player _player;

        public static Player Player => _player;

        static Game()
        {
            _player = new Player("Stepa");

            // Shop.OpenShop();

            Item item = new("Новый предмет", 10000, 456, 987, ItemType.Weapon, ItemSize.Large);
            

            _player.Inventory.PrintInventory();
            Console.WriteLine();

            _player.Inventory.AddItemInInventory(item);

            _player.Inventory.PrintInventory();
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine($"Protection { _player.Inventory.TotalProtection}");
            Console.WriteLine($"ProtectionQuality { _player.Inventory.TotalProtectionQuality}");

            Init();
        }
        private static void Init()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Game Init");
            Console.WriteLine();

            //Shop.OpenShop();

        }

        public static void GameProcess()
        {
        Batlle:
            Battle.BattlePVE(World.CurrentLvl.TakeFighter());
            if (_player.Params.Health <= 0 && _player.Lifes <= 0)
                goto GameOver;
            else
            {
                if (_player.Params.Health <= 0)
                    _player.Respawn();

                Console.WriteLine("Нажмите ENTER для продолжения игры");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Clear();
                goto EveryStep;
            }

        EveryStep:
            _player.Gold += 5;
            _player.Regeneration();
            goto Batlle;

        GameOver:
            Console.WriteLine("Game over");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Это скрип в котором я вызываю метод, который добавляет предмет в инвентарь.
Это структура Item.

```
namespace FightGame.Structs
{
    public struct Item
    {
        private string _name;
        private int _cost;
        private int _protection;
        private int _protectionQuality;
        private bool _onEquiped = false;
        private ItemType _type;
        private ItemSize _size;

        public string Name => _name;
        public int Cost => _cost;
        public int Protection
        {
            get => _protection;
            set => _protection = value;
        }

        public int ProtectionQuality
        {
            get => _protectionQuality;
            set => _protectionQuality = value;
        }
        public bool OnEquiped => _onEquiped;
        public ItemType Type => _type;
        public ItemSize Size => _size;

        public Item(string name, int cost, int protection, int protectionQuality, ItemType type, ItemSize size)
        {
            _name = name;
            _cost = cost;
            _protection = protection;
            _protectionQuality = protectionQuality;
            _type = type;
            _size = size;
        }

        public static Item GenerateItem(string name, int cost, int protection, int protectionQuality, int spread)
        {
            Random rand = new();
            //* Генерация числа 
            int GenerateNumber(int number)
            {
                if (spread == 0 && spread < 0)
                    return number;

                int minNum = cost - (int)(cost * 0.2);
                int maxNum = cost + (int)(cost * 0.2);
                return rand.Next(minNum, maxNum);
            }

            //* Генерация случайного типа
            ItemType GenerateItemType()
            {
                switch (rand.Next(Enum.GetNames(typeof(ItemType)).Length))
                {
                    case 0:
                        return ItemType.Weapon;
                    case 1:
                        return ItemType.Shield;
                    case 2:
                        return ItemType.Accessories;
                    default:
                        return ItemType.Weapon;
                }
            }

            //* Генерация случайного размера
            ItemSize GenerateItemSize()
            {
                switch (rand.Next(Enum.GetNames(typeof(ItemSize)).Length))
                {
                    case 0:
                        return ItemSize.Small;
                    case 1:
                        return ItemSize.Medium;
                    case 2:
                        return ItemSize.Large;
                    default:
                        return ItemSize.Small;
                }
            }

            return new Item(name, GenerateNumber(cost), GenerateNumber(protection),
            GenerateNumber(protectionQuality), GenerateItemType(), GenerateItemSize());
        }

        public void PrintItemInfo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name " + _name);
            Console.WriteLine("Cost " + _cost);
            Console.WriteLine("Protection " + _protection);
            Console.WriteLine("Protection Quality " + _protectionQuality);
            Console.WriteLine("Size " + _size);
            Console.WriteLine("Type " + _type);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    public enum ItemType
    {
        Weapon,
        Shield,
        Accessories
    }

    public enum ItemSize
    {
        Small,
        Medium,
        Large
    }
}
```

Точка входа программы

```
static void Main()
        {
            //Настройка UI
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.Clear();

            World.SetLevels(GenerateLevels());
            
            Game.GameProcess();


            // World.PrintLevels();
        }
```

Comment: Вангую: Вы делаете постоянно `Inventory inventory = new();` где-то и как-то (например вызываете повторно `GenerateInventory()`, ну а новый инвентарь == новые значения. Показывайте весь код, если не найдете причину сами.

Comment: `struct Inventory` - вот причина проблем. Замените на `class`.

Comment: @peter Почему так происходит? Можно ли обойти это используя структуру?